# How do you activate alpinejs?

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I'm trying to add AlpineJS to a very simple html page that I'm working on and the package is being executed (from cdn) but it doesn't seem to get activated correctly. Even on this small snippet of HTML, it doesn't work:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 x-show="false">hide me</h1> <!-- doesn't work-->
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log($el); //undefined
    </script>
</html>
```

This is also loaded into a codepen where the problem can be observed: https://codepen.io/dwarburt/pen/gOgZyeR

I'm sure I've just missed a step, but what could it be? AlpineJS is executing its initialization routines, you can tell from the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To initialise an AlpineJs component you'll need an `x-data` attribute on the parent container:

```
<div x-data="{
    isShowing: false
}">
    <h1 x-show="isShowing">I am hidden</h1>
</div>
```

This contains an object with properties and functions you can use within the component instance.

It's definitely worth reading through the docs in the repo here: https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine#use

Comment: Thanks, I had read those docs, of course.  The examples show parent elements with `x-data` but I didn't know that was required, even if your sub-components are not going to be using the x-data object. After I added `x-data`  (just the attribute with no value) to the parent element, then the `x-show="false"` directive started working like I expected. Why does it work like this? And also, `$el` is still undefined, why is that the case? https://codepen.io/dwarburt/pen/QWdzXvK

Comment: Crawling the whole DOM to find a load of tags and directives is expensive so `x-data` lets AlpineJs know that a specific portion of the page is an AlpineJs component; much more performant. In order to `console.log` the `$el`, you'll need to do that from within the component. I'd take a look at `x-init` which runs when a component is initialised `x-init="console.log($el)"`: https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine#x-init

Comment: Doesn't it have to crawl the entire DOM to find any `x-data` elements then, though?

Comment: For sure but `x-data` marks out smaller sections of the page that are AlpineJs aware. Once you have those sections you can more efficiently walk a smaller part of the tree with all the rest of the queries involved.

Answer (score 0):

I have adjusted your example in order to achieve the result you require,  along with an additional example so you can see how multiple object properties can exist and used within your Alpine.js components.

`x-data` does not need to be initiated on the body tag, however nested components will retrieve the object property from the closest `x-data` property match.

You can access from child nodes of nested `x-data` objects the properties.

Careful of your property naming conventions if you don't wish to overwrite proceeding object properties.

I would also suggest reading [Build a Drop Down](https://alpinejs.dev/start-here#building-a-dropdown) along with [Toggle Element](https://alpinejs.dev/start-here#toggling-elements)

Reading these points will be helpful in understanding the below example in further detail.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body x-data="{show: false, button: 'Toggle'}">
  <button @click="show = ! show" x-text="button"></button>

  <span x-show="show">
  <h1 @click.outside="show = false">hide me</h1> <!-- doesn't work-->
</span>

</body>

</html>
```